# Need to change where Flash links to

Tags: flash

I have a page with a Flash animation being used for the logo. When the user clicks the logo it's supposed to take them to a different URI. Unfortunately, that URI no longer exists.

I don't have the Flash Pro from Adobe. Is there another way to edit this animation so I can change where it links to?

If I absolutely can't change it, I'm thinking about maybe over-riding it with Javascript, but I'm not sure if that would work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a program called flasm. http://flasm.sourceforge.net/

It is a Flash compiler/decompiler that is Free.

This will decompile the swf file to its byte code. Do not worry about being able to read it. Just open the code in a text editor and search for the url string.

Change the URL string and then recompile with flasm.

That will take care of your problem.

Their web site gives complete instructions

Comment: In disassembled code I can't see the link, just metadata and list of defineMovieClip blocks. Is it how it should be?

Comment: If opened in a text editor, try searching for specific text within the disassembled code. This is how I do it. It should be pretty obvious once you get to that section. However, it will not look like regular ActionScript.

Comment: I think in my case the problem is that it is not able to disassemble AS3.